# Making floating point numbers below some tolerance 0.0

Tags: floating-point, numbers, julia, precision

After some computations, I have a matrix of floating point numbers with some very small *negative* entries (e.g. -2.6e-9) which are approximating 0.

I know that this matrix should be positive definite i.e. all positive eigenvalues, however, I suspect that these approximately 0 but *negative* entries are making the matrix not positive definite, and hence I can't do a further computation I want to do (Cholesky decomposition, for those wondering).

**My question is this**: is there anyway I can force these extremely small entries negative entries which are approximating 0 to be 0.0?

I think I am misunderstanding floating point numbers here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, one relatively easy way to do this with an arbitrary tolerance might be with `isapprox`. For example:

```
julia> A = fill(-2.6e-9, 5,5)
5×5 Matrix{Float64}:
 -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9
 -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9
 -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9
 -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9
 -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9  -2.6e-9

julia> map!(x -> isapprox(x, 0, atol=1e-8) ? 0 : x, A, A)
5×5 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Note that doing this with `map!` will not allocate, so should be quite efficient:

```
julia> @btime map!(x -> isapprox(x, 0, atol=1e-8) ? 0 : x, $A, $A)
  30.984 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

if you don't specify a tolerance (what the `atol` option is doing above) it will choose a reasonable default for general floating point work using a somewhat complicated formula:

```
  isapprox(x, y; atol::Real=0, rtol::Real=atol>0 ? 0 : √eps, nans::Bool=false[, norm::Function])

  Inexact equality comparison. Two numbers compare equal if their relative distance or
  their absolute distance is within tolerance bounds: isapprox returns true if norm(x-y)
  <= max(atol, rtol*max(norm(x), norm(y))). The default atol is zero and the default
  rtol depends on the types of x and y. The keyword argument nans determines whether or
  not NaN values are considered equal (defaults to false).

  For real or complex floating-point values, if an atol > 0 is not specified, rtol
  defaults to the square root of eps of the type of x or y, whichever is bigger (least
  precise). This corresponds to requiring equality of about half of the significand
  digits. Otherwise, e.g. for integer arguments or if an atol > 0 is supplied, rtol
  defaults to zero.
```

As to whether anything is going wrong in your previous calculations: not necessarily, given that rounding error is an unavoidable part of working with fixed-precision floating point numbers. However `-2.6e-9` does sound a bit large compared to

```
julia> eps(0.0)
5.0e-324
```

so it depends on what exactly you're doing. If you're, e.g., subtracting two large but similar floats from each other, then this level of error might not be surprising for `Float64`s

Answer (score 5):

There are several nice answers to your question, so let me comment on how to make your matrix positive definite if you have roundoff errors. The simplest way is to add a small diagonal matrix to your original matrix. Let me give an example. Taking the following matrix:

```
julia> A = fill(-2.6e-12, 5, 5)
5×5 Matrix{Float64}:
 -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12
 -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12
 -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12
 -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12
 -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12  -2.6e-12
```

you will not make it positive definite by making all small negative values equal to `0`. But if instead you add some small values to its diagonal it becomes positive definite:

```
julia> A + sqrt(eps())*I
5×5 Matrix{Float64}:
  1.48986e-8  -2.6e-12     -2.6e-12     -2.6e-12     -2.6e-12
 -2.6e-12      1.48986e-8  -2.6e-12     -2.6e-12     -2.6e-12
 -2.6e-12     -2.6e-12      1.48986e-8  -2.6e-12     -2.6e-12
 -2.6e-12     -2.6e-12     -2.6e-12      1.48986e-8  -2.6e-12
 -2.6e-12     -2.6e-12     -2.6e-12     -2.6e-12      1.48986e-8

julia> isposdef(A + sqrt(eps())*I)
true
```

In practice you might need to do both things: round small negative values to be `0` (if you know that in your problem negative entries are not possible) and add some small values to the diagonal of your matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is a maths question rather than a programming question, but what result are you using such that the resulting matrix A+cI is positive definite for c small? Clearly it has something to do with the positive diagonal, but I tried looking and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Just to clarify, I can see why it's positive semidefinite - a symmetric matrix with positive diagonals can be made into the covariance matrix of a collection of random variables which is necessarily positive semidefinite. I'm just wondering if I'm missing something obvious as to why it's positive definite.

Comment: if `(e,u)` is an eigenvalue and eigenvector pair of matrix `A` then `Au = eu`. Now notice that `(A+cI)u=Au+cIu=eu+cu=(e+c)u`. So you increase all eigenvalues by `c` if you add `cI` to your matrix `A`. So it is enough to choose `c` that is greater than the absolute value of the smallest eigenvalue (which is negative given your assumptions) to get a positive definite matrix.

Comment: Oh that is very simple and neat, I haven't seen that before, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`A[A .≈ 0.0] .= 0.0`

`≈`, which can be typed with the latex shortcut `\approx<tab>` is shorthand for the `isapprox` function, which you can use directly to set the specific tolerances you wish to use instead.

EDIT: As pointed out, the defaults don't work for testing against 0.0.

`A[isapprox.(A, 0.0, atol = 1e-8)] .= 0.0`

Comment: this doesn't work, `\approx 0` is same as `== 0`. `julia> 0.0 ≈ nextfloat(0.0)
; false`

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily the fastest but seems to work:

```
julia> tol = 1e-5
1.0e-5

julia> X = [0.1 -1e-4 -1e-20; -2.6e-9 0.1 1.1e5]
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
  0.1     -0.0001      -1.0e-20
 -2.6e-9   0.1     110000.0

julia> Y = ifelse.((X .< -tol ) .|  (X .>  0.0 ), X, 0.0)
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.1  -0.0001       0.0
 0.0   0.1     110000.0
```

This has the advantage to **keep** true negative numbers as negative, so you can spot eventual errors.

Answer (score 0):

there is a package to Force Positive-Definiteness on matrices, called [Positive Factorizations.jl](https://github.com/timholy/PositiveFactorizations.jl).

given that you have an H matrix, you can have the positive Cholesky factorization by:

```
using PositiveFactorizations
A = fill(-2.6e-12, 5, 5)
F = cholesky(Positive, A)
```